# configuring scheduling pool in spark using zeppelin, scala and EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

In pyspark I'm able to change to a fair scheduler within zeppelin (on AWS EMR) by doing the following:

```
conf = sc.getConf()
conf.set('spark.scheduler.allocation.file', 
         '/etc/spark/conf.dist/fairscheduler.xml.template')
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", 'production')
```

However if I try something similar in a scala cell it then things continue to run in the FIFO pool

```
val conf = sc.getConf()
conf.set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", 
         "/etc/spark/conf.dist/fairscheduler.xml.template")   
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "FAIR")
```

I've tried so many combinations, but nothing has worked. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with Spark 2.4.  In my case, the problem was resolved by removing the default "spark.scheduler.pool" option in my Spark config.  It might be that your Scala Spark interpreter is set up with spark.scheduler.pool but your python isn't.

I traced the issue to a bug in Spark - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26988.  The problem is that if you set the config property "spark.scheduler.pool" in the base configuration, you can't then override it using setLocalProperty.  Removing it from the base configuration made it work correctly.  See the bug description for more detail.